# Why orderBy timestamp is not working in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

When I try orderBy timestamp (which is set manually in Firestore so I am not doing it client-side) is not fetching anything.

```
var ref = firestore().collection('discounts')
.orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
.orderBy('timestamp', 'asc');
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to order by both document ID and timestamp.  What are you hoping to accomplish with this query?

Comment: Could you post your collection/documents structure? Also consider posting some example values so we can understand better what's your purpose on trying to orderby documentID